# C++ - Checking if a word is palindrome in struct data type

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, types, palindrome

I want to know how to check if a word is palindrome in struct data type or object whatever you want to call it. I want to read a data from file then I need to check if that type of word that I have read is a palindrome or not. Also i need to reverse order of the words but I did that so do not need any help about that.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct lettersStr
{
    string name;
    string object;

};
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    ifstream letter;
    letter.open("letter.txt");
    lettersStr things[200];
    int numberOfThings= 0;
    while(letter >> letter[numberOfThings].name >> letter[numberOfThings].object)
    {
        numberOfThings++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThings; i++)
    {
        cout << letter[i].name << " " << letter[i].object<< endl;
    }
    string names;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThings; i++)
    {
        names= things[i].name;
    }

    for (int i = numberOfThings- 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << things[i].name << endl;
    }
    bool x = true;
    int j = names.length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++,j--)
    {
        if (things[i].name.at(i) != things[i].name.at(j))
        x = false;

        if (x)
        {
            cout << "String is a palindrome ";
        }
        else
        cout << "String is not a palindrome";
    }
```

And here is the cout:

```
Kayak Audi
Ahmed Golf7
Ahmed
Kayak
String is not a palindrome
String is not a palindrome
```

I think major problem is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++,j--)
    {
        if (things[i].name.at(i) != things[i].name.at(j))
        x = false;
```

As you can see it wont cout right way of checking if a word is palindrome or not.
P.S: If this is a stupid question I am sorry, I am a beginner in C++ programming.
Cheers

Comment: there are no stupid questions, but it isnt quite clear what is the problem. What is wrong with the code? What is the expected output?

Comment: Take a look at the example @ [std::equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal). It does the palindrome check rather nicely.

Comment: You have `for (int i = 0; i < j; i++,j--)` but then `if (things[i].name.at(i) != things[i].name.at(j))`. Is this loop supposed to iterate through `things` or through _one_ `name`? It can't do both at once.

Comment: @churill Yes i want it to loop only through names

Comment: Yes, but take a close look what this loop is doing right now. You should make seperate function to check if a string is a palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, `for (int i = 0; i < j; i++,j--)` loops though `things` and the letters of their `name`s simultaneously. You also have to account for cases where you compare a lower and an upper case letter such as the 'K' and 'k' at the beginning and end of 'Kayak'. You can use `std::tolower` for this.

Here is an example ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ohT8b-)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool is_palindrome(std::string name)
{
    if (name.empty())
        return false;


    // As has been pointed out, you can also use std::equal.
    // However, this is closer to your original approach.
    for (unsigned int i = 0, j = name.length()-1; i < j; i++,j--)
    {
        if (std::tolower(name.at(i)) != std::tolower(name.at(j)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

struct lettersStr
{
    string name;
    string object;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    std::vector<lettersStr> vec = {lettersStr{"Kayak","Boat"},lettersStr{"Audi","Car"}};

    for (const auto &obj : vec)
        if (is_palindrome(obj.name))
            std::cout << obj.name << " is a palindrome" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << obj.name << " isn't a palindrome" << std::endl;
}
```

It gives the output:

```
Kayak is a palindrome
Audi isn't a palindrome
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what does "std::vector<lettersStr> vec = {lettersStr{"Kayak","Boat"},lettersStr{"Audi","Car"}};" mean? Beacuse I want to read data from a file and this formation of vector seams really confusing to me.

Comment: This will behave strangely for strings longer than `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @SamedŠkulj It is called list-initialization and just initializes the two elements of the vector. The first element is a `lettersStr` with `name = "Kajak"` and `object = "Boat"`, the second element is named "Audi" and has the `object` field filled with "Car".

Comment: Ok I managed to read from a file with vector. But I have one more question @StefanKssmr. Can you explain me what this line do please? "for (const auto &obj : vec)"

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're right, this solution is far from perfect but I think it works for Samed.

Comment: @StefanKssmr Sure, it'll work until it suddenly doesn't one day :-) You could just use `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Samed This simply loops though the elements of the vector. It is called a range based loop if you want to have more information on that.

Comment: @StefanKssmr Thank you so much. Thank you for helping me out. And yes, this solution will work perfectly for me. Thank you again. Cheers